# Symfony2 simple .htaccess password protect for dev purpose

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, .htpasswd

I would like to use a `.htaccess` file to protect my symfony2 website while developing it.

I added the following line at the beginning of my `.htaccess` located in `/web` and a `.htpasswd` file just next with my password.

```
AuthName "Développement"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

I have a Error 500 when I try to access my website. Is it possible to use a htaccess in my case ? What should I use if it is not posible ?

Comment: First thing you shold always do when you get a 500 error is check your error log. Do that before posting on a forum, that way if the error message doesn't solve your problem you can at least include it in your post.

Comment: @Paulpro You are right, I don't have the reflex yet. In my case I don't have anything in the log file ... (I mean for that issue, last logs are from 4 hours ago)

Comment: Did you check the Apache log, or just Symfony's ? For an issue with `.ht` files I would expect there to be a message in the Apache log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the 500 error is caused by these directives, the most likely reason is the path to `.htpasswd`. [`AuthUserFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile) says

> The AuthUserFile directive sets the name of a textual file containing the list of users and passwords for user authentication. File-path is the path to the user file. **If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the [ServerRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot).**

So either use an absolute path (e.g. `/var/www/.htpasswd`) or add the complete path starting from your document root (e.g. `web/.htpasswd`).

---

Also note the last section in [`AuthUserFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile)

> Security
>   Make sure that the AuthUserFile is stored outside the document tree of the web-server. Do not put it in the directory that it protects. Otherwise, clients may be able to download the AuthUserFile.

This means, store the auth file somewhere else, like `/etc/apache2/htpasswd`.

Comment: You were right, moving the .htpasswd in a other directory with the absolute path in the .htaccess solved the problem